# Injected service is undefined inside of another service in the same module

Tags: nestjs

I have two services in the same module

The *auth/services/auth.service.ts* and *auth/services/token-validator.service.ts*

The *token validator service* is undefined inside of the *auth service*, the curious thing is that the *token validator service* is available inside a controller in another module.

*auth.module.ts*

```js
@Module({
  imports: [AuthService,
    TokenValidatorService,
    HttpModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        timeout: 5000,
        maxRedirects: 3
      }),
    })],
  exports: [AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

*auth/services/token-validator.service.ts*

```js
  export class TokenValidatorService {
    constructor() {}
    
    async validate(token: string, url: string): Promise<boolean> {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

*auth/services/auth.service.ts*

```js
import { TokenValidatorService } from "./token-validator.service";

console.log('Init AuthService ' + TokenValidatorService); // here it prints the class

export class AuthService {
  private userPool: UserPool;

  constructor(
    private readonly tokenValidatorService: TokenValidatorService
  ) {
    console.log(tokenValidatorService); // here it's undefined

    this.userPool = new UserPool('xxx');
  }

  async isAuthorizated(token: string) {
    console.log(this.tokenValidatorService); // here it's undefined
    await this.tokenValidatorService.validate(token);
  }
}
```

*users/controllers/user.controller.ts*

```js
import { TokenValidatorService } from 'src/auth/services/token-validator.service';

@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly tokenService: TokenValidatorService,
    private readonly usersService: UsersService) { }

  @Get('auth')
  async auth() {
    console.log('User controller ' + this.tokenService);

    this.tokenService.validate('',''); // here it works fine

    await this.authService.isAuthorizated("eyJraW.."); // it also works fine
  }
}
```

*tsconfig*

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Decorate the service with `@Injectable()` this will allow it to be injected into other services/controllers/resolvers/decorators etc.

Comment: @DmitriiTkachenko, I added the Injectable decorator, but nestjs complains that the service is already declared as imports in the module, then I removed it from imports and even though it didn't work

Comment: Oh, just noticed: it's not registered as a provider of the `AuthModule`. Add it to the `providers` list.

Comment: @DmitriiTkachenko, it worked!!! Finally, thanks!!

Comment: Why sometimes I need the Injectable decorators and sometimes not?

Comment: No worries. One tip that might save you some time in debugging: https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#debugging-dependency-errors

adding `NEST_DEBUG=true` to your `.env` file will show a verbose log of resolved dependencies. This way you will see if a particular dependency is missing.

TLDR;

Is your dependency annotated with `@Injectable()`?
Is it registered as a provider of the module? Or imported.
Is it exported form the module that contains it?

Answering these questions will cover 95% of DI errors.

Comment: Please, refer to the documentation: https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#dependency-injection. It may sound obvious, but: If you inject it needs to be injectable.
This article might help you: https://blog.stackademic.com/dependency-injection-in-nestjs-68c35b31a09f

Comment: another good article: [NestJS Metadata Deep Dive](https://trilon.io/blog/nestjs-metadata-deep-dive)